# How to properly update an Object using Spring and Hibernate in this scenario?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Got this modal which opens up when the user clicks on the update button:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="edit-modal-title">Editar Credencial</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="edit-credentialsTable">
                        <tr class="row">
                            <th id="edit-modal-user">Usuario</th>
                            <th id="edit-modal-pass">Clave</th>
                            <th id="edit-modal-notes">Notas</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td><input type="text" id="newUser"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="newPass"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="newNotes"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the JS code that posts to the controller:

```
$("#credentialsTable").on('click',"button[id^='edi-']",  (e) => {
    $('#credentialsModal').modal('hide');
    $('#editModal').modal('show');

    var credentialId = e.target.id;
    var newUser = $('#newUser').val();
    var newPass = $('#newPass').val();
    var newNotes = $('#newNotes').val();

    $.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials/update", data => {
    console.log(data);
    });
});
```

but I'm lost from here ... I have no idea how to handle the update to show it in the front-end.

How should I post the values of the new edited fields ? I shouldn't send them in the URL cause I know it's a bad practice, right ?

This is the controller that will handle the post:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fisicHost/{id}/credentials/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateCredential(@PathVariable(value = "id") String credId){
    String[] parts = credId.split("-");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    Credential credential = credentialService.getCredentialById(id);
    credentialService.update(credential);
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to return data from your updateCredential method?

Comment: Sorry for that ... I want to know how to send the data in the body of the post and how to get it back to show it in my front-end ... for these 3 fields:   `var newUser = $('#newUser').val();
    var newPass = $('#newPass').val();
    var newNotes = $('#newNotes').val();`

Comment: You'll want to look up a tutorial on writing REST APIs, the Spring Getting Started Guides are a good place to start for the server.  It looks like jQuery on the client so I'd recommend looking up a tutorial on how to use a REST API with jQuery.

Comment: Well thanks ... I'll check it out :D ... I know how to send data in the URL and get it in the controller with the @PathVariable annotation, but not in the body ... I guess JSON has something to do with this, right ?

Comment: Yep. And the ‘@RequestBody’ annotation will pull the JSON object from the body of the POST request. Spring will map the JSON to a POJO for you at that point.

Comment: Awsome ... thanks for the lesson my friend :)